Spring Boot API on AWS ECS fails with 'Broken pipe' when executing Databricks SQL query
I am trying to execute a SELECT query on Databricks from a Spring Boot API. I have initialized the javax.sql.DataSource with Databricks as the datasource and used the executeQuery() method to run the query.
This service works fine on my local environment. However, when I deploy it to AWS ECS and call the API using Postman, I encounter the following error:
org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: ServletOutputStream failed to write: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleHttpServletResponse.handleIOException(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleServletOutputStream.write(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:401) at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingOutputStream.write(StreamUtils.java:261) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2210)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeFieldName(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:247) ......
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:341)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:776)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:673)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:376)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:354)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:103)

This error does not occur locally but only happens when the service is deployed on AWS ECS.
What I have tried so far:

Verified the query works perfectly in my local environment.
Increased ECS container memory and CPU.
Checked for API Gateway timeouts (if
relevant) and ECS load balancer idle timeouts. No issues found in my
CloudWatch logs related to connection timeouts or load balancer
disconnects.


Please go through mentioned...

Increase timeouts on both the client (Postman) and the Spring Boot application.
Check ECS and Databricks configurations, ensuring no network timeouts or restrictions.
Review async request settings and increase timeouts for long-running queries.
Ensure the query is optimized to reduce execution time.

